# print specific field from first line in file using awk

Tags: awk, line, field

I have a file (logins.txt) that I need to make into a file that only displays the first and last login date/time and the last login date/time. The logins.txt looks like this:

```
Feb 13 2:43 (login IP)
Feb 13 2:48 (login IP)
Feb 13 5:23 (login IP)
Feb 13 9:43 (login IP)
Feb 14 1:34 (login IP)
Feb 14 8:42 (login IP)
Feb 14 8:47 (login IP)
```

I want to print:

```
First Login: Feb 13 2:43
Last Login: Feb 14 8:47
```

Now keep in mind I'm using an .awk file where I have all my awk statements in that executes logins.txt and makes a different file with what I want to print out.

The last login was easy. I simply just put:

```
END{
print "$1, $2, $3";
}
```

Which prints out the last occurrence of those fields.
But how do I do it with the first occurrence?

EDIT:
Awesome, putting NR==1 works but I NEED this in the END field because I need it below other stuff I want to print. How do I put it below everything?
Also I want it to print like this:

```
Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
First Login: Feb 13 2:43      Last Login: Feb 14 8:47
```

Here is my END with print statements

```
NF==1 {a=$1; b=$2; c=$3;}

END{
   print "Feed\t\t\tAccepted\tRejected\tCanceled";
   print "-----------------------------------------------------------------";
   print "swrinde:\t\t", accepted_sw"\t\t", rejected_sw"\t\t", canceled_sw"\t\t";
   print "news.cais.net:\t\t", accepted_ne"\t\t", rejected_ne"\t\t", canceled_ne"\t\t";
   print "\?:\t\t\t", accepted_un"\t\t", rejected_un"\t\t", canceled_un"\t\t";
   print "\nStart Time = ", a, b, c RS "\tEnd Time =", $1, $2, $3;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Qualify another block with `NR==1`:

```
awk 'NR==1 { print "First Login:", $1, $2, $3 } END { print "Last Login:", $1, $2, $3 }' logins.txt
```

Results:

```
First Login: Feb 13 2:43
Last Login: Feb 14 8:47
```

`NR` is short for number of rows. See [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/). HTH.

---

***EDIT1:***

Here's two ways, depending on your style. The first would be considered more correct:

```
awk 'NR==1 { a=$1; b=$2; c=$3 } { print "Blah" } END { print "First Login:", a, b, c  RS "Last Login:", $1, $2, $3 }' logins.txt

awk 'NR==1 { x=("First Login:" FS $1 FS $2 FS $3) } { print "Blah" } END { print x RS "Last Login:", $1, $2, $3 }' logins.txt
```

Results:

```
Blah
Blah
Blah
Blah
Blah
Blah
Blah
First Login: Feb 13 2:43
Last Login: Feb 14 8:47
```

***EDIT2:***

Run your script like:

```
awk -f script.awk logins.txt
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
NR==1 {
    a=$1
    b=$2
    c=$3
}

{
    print "Blah"
}

END {
    print "First Login:", a, b, c  RS "Last Login:", $1, $2, $3
}
```

***EDIT3:***

```
BEGIN { OFS="\t\t" }

NR==1 { a=$1; b=$2; c=$3 }

END{
   print "Feed\t\t\tAccepted\tRejected\tCanceled"
   print "-----------------------------------------------------------------"
   print "swrinde:", accepted_sw, rejected_sw, canceled_sw
   print "news.cais.net:", accepted_ne, rejected_ne, canceled_ne
   print "?:\t", accepted_un, rejected_un, canceled_un

   print "Start Time = " a FS b FS c
   print "End Time = " $1 FS $2 FS $3
}
```

Results:

```
Feed            Accepted    Rejected    Canceled
-----------------------------------------------------------------
swrinde:                        
news.cais.net:                      
?:                          
Start Time = Feb 13 2:43
End Time = Feb 14 8:47
```

Comment: Awesome, putting NR==1 works but I NEED this in the END field because I need it below other stuff I want to print. How do I put it below everything?
Also I want it to print like this:

Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
First Login: Feb 13 2:43           End Login: Feb 14 8:47

Comment: @FredLohrman: Use variables to store what you want. Then print them when you need. I've updated my answer above. HTH.

Comment: The first way just printed out blank spots and I can't do the second way because I need both First Login and Last Login to be in the END{}
I do appreciate your help!

Comment: I might have to type it in differently since I'm using a script file. I know I obviously don't put 'awk' in front when using a script file but is there anything else I need to change? Still getting blanks on the First Login. Also still can't put them side by side.

Comment: @FredLohrman: Two things: 1) You wrote `NF==1` instead of `NR==1`. 2) Set an `OFS` instead of having to write out `"\t\t"` over and over again. By default both `FS` and `OFS` return a single space. When you use commas in your print statements, these are essentially `OFS`. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR==1{x="First Login "$1FS$2FS$3;}END{x=x" last Login "$1FS$2FS$3;print x}' your_file
```

tested [here](http://ideone.com/2DZ4Sd)

Answer (score 0):

Try also using a variable for the last login, because not every awk retains the field values in the END section. For example:

```
awk '{l=$1 FS $2 FS $3} NR==1{f=l} END{ print "First login: " f; print "Last login: " l}' infile
```